# How to prepare Cthulhu Confidential (Gumshoe One-2-One)?

Tags: gm-preparation, one-on-one, gumshoe, gumshoe-one-2-one, cthulhu-confidential

I'm looking for some practical advice on how to prepare for a session of Cthulhu Confidential. I'm a novice GM with some dozens of sessions of other games under my belt, but this will be my first one-2-one session.

A CC scenario (specifically I'm running Fatal Frequencies) is very structured and detailed, with dozens and dozens of facts to keep in your head.

Normally when running with a party of > 2, the GM can use the space where the players are bantering/planning to reference their notes. With CC, consulting notes will result in what is essentially dead-air.

I'd appreciate some practical advice for preparing for a session, or failing that, just "this is how I do it" responses.

- What sorts of notes on NPCs and Scenes do you write? In what format?
- How do you remember quick details of Scenes and NPCs?
- What about all the generic Problems and Edges? How to keep all those in mind?

One answer of course is just "memorize all the things", but I'm looking for more practical tips than that.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.